# Merging list of lists with comma separated in R

Tags: r

I have a data set like that

Reproducible data

```
test <- list(c("1"),c("2"),c("3"),c(c("a"),c("b")),c("d"))
```

Desired output is:

```
1
2
3
a,b
d
```

I have tried

```
output <- do.call(rbind, test)
```

Comment: Please make your desired output clearer. Do you expect a printout or a data structure what data structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you are already close to your goal. Maybe the code below can help you

```
> do.call(rbind, Map(toString, test))
     [,1]
[1,] "1"
[2,] "2"
[3,] "3"
[4,] "a, b"
[5,] "d"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `toString` to collapse every element in the list.

```
out <- data.frame(result = sapply(test, toString))
out
#  result
#1      1
#2      2
#3      3
#4   a, b
#5      d
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/) methods

1. Loop over the `list` with `map`
2. Paste the elements using `str_c`
3. Return a single column dataset by adding the suffix `_dfr` in `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map_dfr(test, ~ tibble(col1 = str_c(.x, collapse=",")))
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  col1 
  <chr>
1 1    
2 2    
3 3    
4 a,b  
5 d
```

Comment: I wanted to do the same, but I have some NA values in my list of lists. The code provided in this answer preserves NAs while the toString will coerce them to "NA". However, with long lists, this code is slower than do.call or sapply. Is there any way of preserving NAs?

Comment: @eggrandio something like `map_dfr(test, ~ if(all(is.na(.x))) NA_character_ else tibble(col1 = str_c(.x[complete.cases(.x)], collapse=",")))`

Comment: I meant that your first answer already kept NA values, but it was slower than `do.call(rbind, Map(toString, test))` or `out <- data.frame(result = sapply(test, toString))`. However, as those use toString, that coerces NA into "NA" strings, so I cannot use them

Comment: @eggrandio In that case you can use `sapply(test, \(x) toString(x[complete.cases(x)]))`  I haven't checked the benchmarks.  Sometimes the base R functions are faster

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this could help too beside all the very good answers you received:

```
test |> 
  lapply(\(x) paste(x, collapse = ",")) |>
  cbind()

     [,1] 
[1,] "1"  
[2,] "2"  
[3,] "3"  
[4,] "a,b"
[5,] "d"
```